# Can't use PHP extension Solr in Ubuntu 13.10 (Apache)

Tags: apache2, php, 13.10, solr

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, the local development version of my website stopped working with a PHP warning:

```
include(SolrQuery.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I checked the pecl solr extension is installed:

```
> sudo pecl install solr
pecl/solr is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.2
```

I checked the Solr Apache extension is set up:

```
> cat /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini
extension=solr.so
```

Any idea where the problem could be?

---

The command `php -m` doesn't seem to show solr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix was to uninstall and then reinstall the solr pecl extension:

```
sudo pecl uninstall solr
sudo pecl install -n solr
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

Before uninstalling, I noticed the `solr.so` was in the wrong place (`/usr/lib/php5/20100525/solr.so`). After uninstalling and reinstalling, it is in `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/solr.so` which is found by Apache, etc.